# Call a function pointer only if it isn't null

Tags: c++, function, pointers, c-preprocessor

I currently use this code in C++ to call a function pointer if it isn't null (I have a few events like onCreate, onDestroy, etc, that are function pointers that can be assigned):

```
#define AssertiveCall(_fn, _args) \
    { \
        if (_fn != nullptr) \
        { \
            return (_fn##_args); \
        } \
    }
```

I would like to convert this into a template, so that I still get the benefit of shorthand but without the ugliness of the `#define macro`. How could I do it?

Comment: I'm compiling with Visual Studio so I can't use varidic templates.

Comment: how many diff args? just make 1 template for each number of args and overload?

Comment: How is `_fn##_args` supposed to work as it stands?

Comment: wouldn't it just be easier to use a no-op/stub function instead of a `nullptr`?, that way you can place the call regardless (it may even prove useful later on, for debugging purposes...)

Comment: Hmm, I would need multiple null functions then, for each different arguments, then?

Comment: @CharlesBailey ## is a lateral appendation, so `AssertiveCall(OnDestroy, (hWnd));` works out like *OnDestroy(hWnd).

Comment: Your macro has a "trick feature", that it conditionally returns from the function that uses it, and otherwise control continues to the statement following the macro. Is that a required feature? It's not possible to do that in a function -- either to force a return from the calling code or to pass control back to the next statement without returning something. Plenty of people would argue that it shouldn't be done in a macro either.

Comment: @kvanberendonck: No `##` is token pasting. The result of concatenating the two sides of the operator must result in a valid single preprocessor token. If this wer the case in your example then `_fn##_args` will resolve to a single token which can't result in a function call. `OnDestroy(hWnd)` is not a token; I think you need to delete the `##` operator.

Comment: I suspect the "trick feature" Steve Jessop identified is actually a bug in your macro.  Macros don't use `return` -- are you sure you didn't mean simply `_fn##_args;`?  That will call `_fn` and then resume execution below the macro call, as you (probably?) expect.

Comment: @kvanberendonck: you can fake up variadic templates by writing a version of the template with zero function args, another with 1, etc as far as you think you need to go. That's how Boost implements certain things in the absence of variadic templates. Then once MSVC++ has the feature you need, replace it.

Comment: Hmm, it's part of a switch loop so it's actually unintentional and not important to my programs execution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For reference, an implementation with variadic templates - in case somebody else has a similar problem and can use variadic templates:

```
template <typename Return, typename ...Parameters, typename ...Args>
auto AssertiveCall(Return (*function)(Parameters...), Args&& ...args)
    -> Return
{
    if (function != nullptr) {
        return (*function)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } else {
        return Return{};
    }
}
```

Comment: If `return Return{}` proves inconvenient, then this function could perhaps return a `boost::optional<Return>`.

Comment: Can this be solved without variadic templates, i.e. pre C++11 times?